# For React, if we used "create-react-app hello-world" to create the app, is there a command to lint all JS files?

Tags: reactjs

If we used

```
create-react-app hello-world
```

to create the React app, is there a command to lint all JS files that we added later, and possibly validate all HTML and CSS files?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says that you should be getting console lint statements automatically while [running the app in development mode](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-start) with `npm start`

If you are looking for linting in your editor, you need to configure that. See the two sections:

[Syntax Highlighting in the Editor](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#syntax-highlighting-in-the-editor)

and right below that

[Displaying Lint Output in the Editor](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#syntax-highlighting-in-the-editor)

Comment: Also you'll get lint output if you run `npm run build`. There is currently no separate command for linting.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I just saw in the npm start terminal screen that `warning  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images`, so it is linting the HTML... for the JS, I removed a semicolon but npm start screen didn't say anything, and then I created an unused local variable and it said something about it. Is there a way to get it to lint the semicolon too?

Comment: @DanAbramov By the way `npm run build` didn't show anything on screen... do I need an option flag or is the linting info stored in a file?

Comment: @太極者無極而生 you can see the list of rules and their settings [HERE](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/eslint-config-react-app/index.js)

Comment: looks like they don't have a semicolon rule... and I saw some sample code for React / Redux and they don't use semicolons too... so I wonder if the standard is so... but I thought it usually is recommended to use semicolons

Comment: It is usually recommended imho. The rule you are looking for is [`semi`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi). I'm sure @DanAbramov might be open to a PR :)